# Unresolvable `R_X86_64_NONE` relocation

Tags: c++, elf, unresolved-external, binutils

I'm using [Devtoolset-7](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/) on CentOS 7 and have built Boost 1.65.1 w/ it.
But when I link my application, I've got the following:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib64/libboost_unit_test_framework.a(compiler_log_formatter.o)(.text._ZN5boost9unit_test5utils11string_castINS0_13basic_cstringIKcEEEESsRKT_[_ZN5boost9unit_test5utils11string_castINS0_13basic_cstringIKcEEEESsRKT_]+0x3c): unresolvable R_X86_64_NONE relocation against symbol `_ZTVSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE@@GLIBCXX_3.4'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Searching more info about `R_X86_64_NONE` doesn't give any valuable results: mostly [similar questions](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/2809571) w/o any answer or precise explanation what is this and how to solve it.

So my questions are:

- what is this error really means?
- what is `R_X86_64_NONE` and why "nothing to relocate" (according to bintils sources) type of symbol ever exists in ELF headers?

**Addendum**:

- The error happened on linking unit tests executable which is linked against my static library and Boosts' static libraries (unit tests framework)
- All static libraries (Boost and mine one) has built with `-fPIC` option

PS. I really want this question to be resolved once and forever (already hit it few times, but this time update to latest binutils doesn't help). (will start a bounty on any activity on this question)

Comment: You might have more luck with a recent LLVM based compiler such as clang (https://reviews.llvm.org/rL288485)

Comment: unfortunately I need GCC 7.x %)

Comment: Have you installed GCC 7 yourself? Did you build Boost yourself? With the same compiler/linker and standard library (including *version*) as you use for your application? I haven't had this error myself, but by reading similar questions it mostly seems to be a problem about mismatching compiler/linker/standard library versions.

Comment: I've used GCC/Binutils from Devtoolset 7. Boost has built w/ the RPM spec adopted for SCL and compiled w/ DTS7 toolchain as well.

Comment: @zaufi Can you post a minimal set of object files which trigger this somewhere? You could open a bug in Bugzilla, for instance. I have never seen any object files which trigger this, and no one apparently has filed a proper bug report.

Comment: @zaufi, I need the exact linker invocation (as shown with `g++ -v`) and a tarball with all the input files (at least those which are not part of the distribution/software collection).

Comment: @FlorianWeimer, please tell me the bug tracker URL to post it (I don't this SO is a right place for that %)

Comment: [Developer Toolset, `binutils` component](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Red%20Hat%20Developer%20Toolset&component=binutils) This is the component which contains the linker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165180/discussion-between-zaufi-and-florian-weimer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [build log posted to the Red Hat Bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1545386#c4):

```
[19:15:01]W:     [Step 8/12] + /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
[19:15:01]W:     [Step 8/12] + /usr/lib/rpm/brp-scl-compress /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root
[19:15:01]W:     [Step 8/12] + /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
[19:16:40]W:     [Step 8/12] /usr/bin/strip: /work/build/BUILDROOT/devtoolset-7-boost-1.65.1-4.el7.centos.x86_64/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/lib64/libboost_container.a(global_resource.o): invalid relocation type 42
[19:16:40]W:     [Step 8/12] /usr/bin/strip: BFD version 2.25.1-32.base.el7_4.2  assertion fail elf64-x86-64.c:341
```

Note `/usr/bin/strip`, not `/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/strip`. So the system `strip` command is used.  42 corresponds to the `R_X86_64_REX_GOTPCRELX` relocation, which is generated by DTS binutils as an optimization.

A simple way to reproduce this is with this C++ file:

```
#include <iostream>

void
dot ()
{
  std::cout << '.';
}
```

If compile with `-O2 -fpic`, it will produce an `X86_64_REX_GOTPCRELX` relocation for `_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev`.  Running `/usr/bin/strip -g` on that will turn that into `R_X86_64_NONE`.  This can be verified using `eu-readelf -r`.

You can use RPM to tell to use the DTS `strip` using

```
%if 0%{?scl:1}
%define __strip %{_bindir}/strip
%endif
```

in the RPM spec file, or you can add

```
%undefine __brp_strip_static_archive
```

to skip stripping the static library completely (which is probably the right thing to do anyway).