# CMake uses gcc from devtoolset but links against wrong libgcc and libstd++

Tags: gcc, cmake, devtoolset

I have a project with CMake, devtoolset-6 and standart gcc 4.8.2 installed.
CMake correctly finds correct gcc:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.2.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
```

PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH are set

```
echo $PATH
/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/lib64:/opt/rh/devtoolset-6/root/usr/lib
```

The project builds correctly but lings against wrong libgcc and libstd++ from /usr/lib64

```
  libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f60b47bf000)
  libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f60b45a8000)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Is LD_LIBRARY_PATH still set when you run ldd? Is the binary suid? Actually, is there a more recent libstdc++.so.6 in devtoolset-6/root/usr/lib64? My understanding is that they use the system one, and link with some static library to add the missing symbols.

Comment: Both questions - yes

Comment: If the binary is suid, then LD_LIBRARY_PATH is useless. You would need to set the rpath, but as explained in my updated comment, I don't think that's necessary with devtoolset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, but the feature! :)
RH DevToolset is not just an alternative compiler built on the side. It's `libstdc++` is an LD script. The new C++11 (and above) symbols in your binary would be resolved via **static** library (built specially and shipped w/ DTS). However, old symbols (existed in the OS's shipped `libstdc++`) going to be resolved dynamically. That is why `ldd` shows you `libstdc++` from the `/usr/lib64`! Also, it has *Old C++ ABI* by default... to make your modern C++ code compatible w/ old `libstdc++` DSO.

This feature allows you to use modern C++ standards, and produce a binary which can be executed in the original OS (CentOS/RHEL) **w/o any additional "redistributable" shared libraries**.

JFYI, if you use `strip`, make sure you use it from DTS and **not the "native" one** (shipped in `binutils` from the OS)! Otherwise, [really bad things can happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706962/unresolvable-r-x86-64-none-relocation).