# glib:unresolvable R_X86_64_NONE relocation against symbol `strncmp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: gcc, linker-errors, glibc, glib

I am hitting following issue while linking.

Command:-

```
gcc -m64 -shared -fPIC -o libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.1 -Wl,--whole-archive libglib-2.0.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Error:-

```
 BFD: libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gcompletion.o): invalid relocation type 42
 BFD: BFD version 2.20.51.0.2-5.36.el6 20100205 assertion fail elf64-x86-64.c:290
 .....
 .....
 .....
/usr/bin/ld: libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gcompletion.o)(.text+0x55): unresolvable R_X86_64_NONE 
relocation against symbol `strncmp@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gbacktrace.o)(.text+0x47): unresolvable R_X86_64_NONE 
relocation against symbol `stdout@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
```

i built my libraries 'libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.1','libglib-2.0.a' with gcc 6.3. Please help me in fixing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unresolvable \`R\_X86\_64\_NONE\` relocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706962/unresolvable-r-x86-64-none-relocation)

Comment: Andrew, It did't help me.